# how to charge components dynamically?

Tags: dataflow, total.js

I use the plugin `total.js` flow.
I would like to know if there is a function like `FLOW.Reload()` to dynamically reload the components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Flow supports `FLOW.reload()` method.

```
FLOW.reload([type], [callback]);
// +v6.0.0 Can reload a Flow
// @type {Number} 0 reloads only designer + variables (default), 1 reloads components + designer + variables
// @callback {Function} A callback
```

Comment: Other way isn't possible. If my answer is not sufficient then I need to know what you need specifically, what is your case?